# How to prove $i^n$ is divergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, epsilon-delta

How do I prove that $s_n=i^n$ is divergent in Complex space ?

Proving something not divergent is slightly difficult. Because I have to find two parameters $\epsilon$ and $n \geq N$ given $N$ and any $s$

Comment: Try finding two subsequences that go to different limits.(Hint: even $n$ and odd $n$)

Comment: Rather $n=4k$ and $n=4k+2$.

Comment: I want to prove using definition. without any property of subsequence.

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged as complex analysis?

Comment: This suggestion corresponds to "using the definition without any property of subsequence" in every sense I can fathom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful when you take the negation of the definition of convergence:

For any potential limit $L$, there exists a gap $\epsilon >0$ such that for any $N$, there is some $n>N$ for which $|x_n - L| > \epsilon$.

This approach needs you to show that it does not converge to any limit value.

---

Another way: If going with marty's answer, you would want to negate the definition of Cauchy sequence:

There exists $\epsilon$ such that for any $N$, there exists $m,n>N$ for which $|x_n - x_m| > \epsilon$  .
In this case you can take $\epsilon$ to be anything $<1$, like $1/2$.

... and if the sequence is not Cauchy, then it cannot converge.

Answer (score 6):

$|i^n-i^{n+1}|>1$,
so it can never converge.